# Display doc file in browser using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a job portal using asp.net. I need to build a control to display the uploaded resume on the browser from the server directory. Could any one share the code to do the same. what is the control appropriate to display the content of a doc file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ASP.NET server control to display a Word document in a web-page. Microsoft removed the Internet Explorer-only ability to show Word documents in the browser with Office 2007, but before then you could have gotten away with doing it in an `<iframe>` - note that this does require Word to be installed on the browser's computer.

It sounds like you want to convert the Word document into HTML+CSS. I'll stop you right here, because that is a non-trivial operation, even with the significantly-easier-to-process OOXML file formats. There are commercial libraries that can assist you with this, but they cost $lots. (Bing for "Aspose").

There are a few other alternatives:

- Print the document, server-side, to a PDF file. This needs a complicated set-up on the server as the Office COM automation libraries should not be used from headless (e.g. server) code; so you'd need to set-up some kind of GUI-session daemon to do this processing.
- Accept only the OOXML file formats and extract only plaintext content (this can be done easily enough without much knowledge of OOXML if you already have experience with manipulating XML in-code).
- Accept only plaintext or HTML submissions. This is how most "upload your resume" sites work, including Apple's and Microsoft's careers websites.

If you just want to return the Word document to your visitors, then just return the raw bytes of the file using Response.WriteFile, or write directly to the Response's output stream if you're persisting the Word document outside of the filesystem.

Comment: string path = //my path here//
string temppath = rs.resume_URL;
        /temppath;

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
{
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
StringBuilder strbuild = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string s in readText)
{
strbuild.Append(s);
strbuild.AppendLine();
}
txtresume.Text = strbuild.ToString();
}
}
i used the above code to read the content of the file. 

Now the problem is, the code is displaying the image content as garbage value. how to resolve it. Please help its very Urgent

Comment: string path = //my path here//
string temppath = rs.resume_URL;
        /temppath;

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
{
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
StringBuilder strbuild = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string s in readText)
{
strbuild.Append(s);
strbuild.AppendLine();
}
txtresume.Text = strbuild.ToString();
}
}
i used the above code to read the content of the file. 

Now the problem is, the code is displaying the image content as garbage value. how to resolve it. Please help its very Urgent

Comment: This isn't something we can help you with. You need to rephrase your question because it's unclear if you're talking about plaintext documents or Word documents. And what images?

Comment: My requirement is to display the uploaded resume just like it appears in the word document. the word document includes images text etc.

Comment: I'm afraid your requirement isn't really possible unless you have the budget for a Doc-to-HTML library or the time (and technical competence) to do implement it yourself.